# PCIe - 16 add-on video card issue

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card, bios, pci-express

Had an ADI Radeon (HP OEM) PCIe-16 working fine in a Lenovo K450n until about the time of the Windows 10 1709 update.  Got a call from the guy running the presentation saying that video no longer works.  It was working fine for well over a year with no issues.

Bought a new nVidia GeForce 210 and it does not work either.  In fact, the card does not display any video at system POST - so the issue does not appear to be an OS issue, but rather a hardware problem.  The onboard Intel adapter still works fine, so I can get into the BIOS and even still load Windows 10 with no issue.

I have checked Lenovo's website for BIOS and other updates.

I have changed the BIOS from Auto to PCI to PEG and neither option seems to work.  I have an older Dell system and placed the new nVidia card into which works fine.  However, I need to get new card working in the Lenovo, if possible?

Thanks for any insight and guidance.

Comment: I think you mean 1709 instead of 1706.  Of course you could also mean 1703.  Update your question to reflect what you actually meant.

Comment: OK.  Updated.  The basic issue is that I cannot get even a POST when I have a PCIe-16 card attached.  The onboard video works fine.

Comment: So to be clear, your system does not POST, is that correct?  It not passing the power on self-test is different then simply not having any video.  Video is not required for POST to happen (i.e. headless systems exist).

Comment: I know the system does POST, but nothing is on the screen.  The video, when running off of PCIe-16 does not show anything on the monitor.

Comment: HP computers are notoriously finicky with add in cards. I'd be tempted to point at the 25W limit on the slot, but the GT 210 is below that.

Comment: @JMY1000 - I stole the add-in card from an HP computer to be used in a Lenovo.  It worked fine for well over a year.